# Mirror partial image on UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to make something similar to this:

[image]

I am not sure how to mirror images translucently like this person has done on the tom and bottom toolbars.

I have the album art saved in a `UIImage`....can I select just the top portion of it and flip it on the top toolbar and flip the bottom on the bottom toolbar?  Keeping in mind I need this on two separate toolbars, can these be done on a `UIToolbar`?  And how do I get that translucent look?

Comment: This is just a gradient image with transparency, layered over the album art. Just make a gradient in **PhotoShop**, and add it to a `UIImageView`.

Comment: The album art itself?  or the image laid on the toolbar?

Comment: The image laid on the toolbar. All you need to do is make the transparent gradient in **PhotoShop**. For the mirrored effect, simply add a `UIImageView` behind each transparent toolbar, and set the image of each to be the album art. Then, transform those `UIImageView`'s with `.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f);`. Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are simply UIImageViews flipped along the x-axis with a gradient drawn over it.
Have a look at the code sample. You might need to vary colors and adjust the frame, start and stop colors...

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAGradientLayer.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: coverImage];
//flip the view
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imgView.transform, 1, -1);
CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
frame.size.height = 50.0; //or any other value
imgView.frame = frame;
self.imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
self.imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
//set the gradient
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.frame = self.imgView.bounds;
UIColor *startCol = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green: 1.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 0.5];
UIColor *endCol = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1.0 green: 1.0 blue: 1.0 alpha: 1];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (id)startCol.CGColor, (id)endCol.CGColor, nil];
layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
[self.imgView.layer addSublayer: layer];
```